# dynamic JSP background color

Tags: css, jsp

I have an html form that is submitted to a JSP. The form has an input that specifies background color preference. On the JSP page, I am trying to use the background color specified by the user, or, if they do not enter anything, use a color specified in a CSS file. Is this possible?

I have a  in my jsp that specifies the location of the CSS file, so I know I can get to the css background color, but if the user specifies a color, I want to 'ignore' that, and use the color they chose.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the default css via a `<link href...>`, and then add the overrides in a `<style>` block on the page. Since the styles defined on the `style` block will have precedence over the other ones it will successfully override the default values. You can see more about how CSS "cascades" the styles on the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade).

Try something like this in the `<head>`

```
<link href="default.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    /* Define custom CSS by the user here */
    body{
        background-color: <% ... %>;
    }
</style>
```

I suppose there are many ways of producing the correct output in JSP, but using [JSTL Core IF Tag](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/5-jstl-core-if-tag-examples-in-jsp.html) you could do something like the following:

```
<style>
    /* Define custom CSS by the user here */
    body{
        <core:if test="${param.backgroundColor!= null}">
            background-color: <%=request.getParameter("backgroundColor")%>
        </core:if>
    }
</style>
```

This way if the user has selected a custom `background-color` for the `h1` element, it will override the default.

Comment: Ok, so inside the scriptlet tag I would get the parameter from the request(the color), and if it is null, what do I do?

Comment: @user1154644 I have updated my answer with a way in which you could do that.

Comment: Is there a reason it is wrapped in a h1 block?

Comment: @user1154644 that is just an example, you could put any block that you want to style. I changed my answer so that it overrides the body background color